# crontab not executing a working shell script

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have a script of the following format:

---

> #!/bin/bash
>
> cd /abc/def/user1/test
>
> export NIMBUS_ENV_FILE=/abc/def/user1/test/nimbus_env
>
> main/vdnet -c yaml/config.yaml -t ABC.*.*.*

---

my script executes perfectly when run from the shell.I want to execute this script daily and so i have set a cron job for the same by editing crontab -e as :

---

> PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:.
>
> 00 12 * * * /home/test.sh > /home/testCronLog.log 2>&1

---

### Hoever, the cron job is run but it does not run the script as expected and gives following errors:

> main/vdnet: line 2: readlink: command not found
>
> dirname: missing operand
>
> Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
>
> main/vdnet: line 3: /../main/environment: No such file or directory
>
> main/vdnet: line 8: /../scripts/nimbus/setup: No such file or
>   directory
>
> main/vdnet: line 14: /../main/vdNet.pl: No such file or directory

---

I do not get these errors when I manually execute the script and am not able to figure out whats wrong.The owner of the script is same as the crontab user.
Please Help!!!

Comment: give the full path of `main/vdnet` in your script

Answer (score 1):

The issue is now resolved. 
I added the path to the script before running my command main/vdnet :
export PATH=...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you use some command or something, or your script, its always better to give full path
so give full path of `main/vdnet` in your script

Comment: i have already done a 'cd ' in the script before main/vdnet. However, i tried giving the full path too. But did not work. It gives the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the line which calls vdnet line in test.sh to:

```
main/vdnet -c /abc/def/user1/testyaml/config.yaml -t ABC...*
```

Your problem I think is that although test.sh runs perfectly from crontab, main/vdnet does not, and that is because the reference you have supplied it as the argument to the -c option needs the full path.

Comment: tried this too. even this did not work. And i fail to understand the need to add the full path if i am doing a cd to that directory before executing the main/vdnet command.

Comment: same errors as before:main/vdnet: line 2: readlink: command not found
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
main/vdnet: line 3: /../main/environment: No such file or directory
main/vdnet: line 8: /../scripts/nimbus/setup: No such file or directory
main/vdnet: line 14: /../main/vdNet.pl: No such file or directory

Comment: try:

    /bin/bash main/vdnet -c /abc/def/user1/test/yaml/config.yaml -t ABC...*

Comment: even this did not help.